# Error using library: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, jsx

I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/adarshpastakia/ant-extensions/tree/master/modules/searchbar

I'm testing it on a codesandbox and it should work, but I get this error:
**Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. **

My code

```
import "./styles.css";
import { SearchBar } from "@ant-extensions/searchbar";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <SearchBar
        collapsed={false}
        filters={[]}
        fields={[]}
        emptyField={"Message when fields list is empty"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-snowflake-7c3mz?file=/src/App.js

Comment: This is a TypeScript package and you are using it in the JS,

Comment: @UmairRiaz it is an NPM module, the fact that it's written with TypeScript doesn't prevent its use in any project using NPM. The module is compiled to JS, but it also includes additional `.d.ts` files for any potential TypeScript project to use as typings reference.

Comment: I'd create an issue on their Github page, this looks like a bug to me.